# Why isn't the deduction from the input step working as expected?

Tags: html, input

The `step` of the `input` is not working as expected.

For example, the following:

```html
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="0" max="100" step="7" value="100">
```

is resulting in **98** when I `step` one value down in the `input` field, not **93**.

Why is this, and is there a way to fix it?

I also tried it on the latest *Edge*, *Chrome* & *Firefox*, but I experience the same behaviour.

I looked up a search here and on the net: "*input step deduction not as expected*", but nothing relevant did I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the `input` `step` is measured from the `min` value, so if I determine `min="-5"`, it results in a proper deduction, like so:

```html
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-5" max="100" step="7" value="100">
```

Comment: Can you please add a reference to your self-answer?

Comment: I concluded this on my own, without reference. @PM77-1